# Find a substring within a string using processes

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, string-comparison

I have a large file (around 1,000,000 characters) in the format "AATACGTAGCTA" and a subsequent file, such as "CGTATC" (10,240 characters). I want to find the largest match of the subsequence within the main sequence. A full, 100% subsequence match may not exist, this is not guaranteed. For the sake of a smaller example, the above would output: `Longest match is 4/6 starting at position 5.`

I'm working on my C basics, and would like to implement it like so:

- The user chooses how many processes they would like to split the work
  into.
- Each process does 1/nth of the work and updates the shared memory
  values located in the `struct`.
- The longest match (it may not be all characters) is reflected in the
  `struct`, as well as it's starting position, and how many
  characters were matched. See output below.

## Code

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

typedef struct memoryNeeded {
    int start_pos, total_correct;
    char sequence[1038336];
    char subsequence[10240];
    sem_t *sem;
} memoryNeeded;

// Used to check all arguments for validity
int checkArguments(char* p, int argc) {
    char *prcs;
    errno = 0;
    int num;
    long conv = strtol(p, &prcs, 10);

    if (errno!= 0 || *prcs != '\0' || conv > INT_MAX || conv > 50) {
        puts("Please input a valid integer for number of processes. (1-50)");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        num = conv;
        if (argc != 4) {
            puts("\nPlease input the correct amount of command line arguments (4) in"
                    "the format: \n./DNA (processes) (sequence) (subsequence)\n");
            exit(1);
        } else
            printf("Looking for string using %d processes...\n", num);

        return(num);
    }

}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int processes = checkArguments(argv[1], argc);
    key_t shmkey;
    int procNumber, shmid, pid;
    FILE *sequence;
    FILE *subsequence;
    char *buf1, *buf2;

// Create shared memory
    size_t region_size = sizeof(memoryNeeded);
    shmkey = ftok("ckozeny", 5);
    shmid = shmget(shmkey, region_size, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);

    if (shmid < 0) {
        perror("shmget\n");
        exit(1);
    }

// Create structure in shared memory, attach memory and open semaphore
    memoryNeeded *mn;
    mn = (memoryNeeded *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    mn->sem = sem_open("sem", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 1);

    sequence = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    subsequence = fopen(argv[3], "r");

// Get file sizes   
    fseek(sequence, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int sz1 = ftell(sequence);
    rewind(sequence);

    fseek(subsequence, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int sz2 = ftell(subsequence);
    rewind(subsequence);

// Read files into 2 buffers, which are put into struct mn   
    buf1 = malloc(sz1);
    buf2 = malloc(sz2);

    if (sz1 != fread(buf1, 1, sz1, sequence)) {
        free(buf1);
    }
    if (sz2 != fread(buf2, 1, sz2, subsequence)) {
        free(buf2);
    }

// Initialize struct with necessary values
    mn->start_pos = 0;
    mn->total_correct = 0;
    strncpy(mn->sequence, buf1, sz1);
    strncpy(mn->subsequence, buf2, sz2);

    fclose(sequence);
    fclose(subsequence);

// Begin n forks    
    for (procNumber = 0; procNumber < processes; procNumber++) {

        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) {
            sem_unlink("sem");
            sem_close(mn->sem);
            printf ("Fork error.\n");
        } else if (pid == 0)
            break;
    }

    if (pid != 0) {
        while ((pid = waitpid (-1, NULL, 0))){
            if (errno == ECHILD)
                break;
        }

        printf("Best match is at position %d with %d/10240 correct.", mn->start_pos, mn->total_correct);
        printf ("\nParent: All children have exited.\n");
        
        sem_unlink("sem");
        sem_close(mn->sem);
        shmdt(mn);
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);
        exit(0);
    } else {
// this child process will do its 1/nth of the work
        sem_wait(mn->sem);

        printf ("Child(%d) is in critical section.\n", procNumber);
        sleep(1);

        int i = 0;
        int longest, count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < sz1; i += processes) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sz2; j += processes) {
                count = 0;
                while (mn->sequence[i+j] == mn->subsequence[j]) {
                    count++;
                    j++;
                }
                if (count > longest) {
                    longest = count;
                }
            }
        }

// If local match is longer than that of the struct, update and unlock      
        if (longest > mn->total_correct) {
            mn->total_correct = count;
            mn->start_pos = (i - count);
            sem_post(mn->sem);
        } else
// If not - unlock and let next process go                
            sem_post(mn->sem);

        exit(0);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

- The current child code is more or less "pseudocode". I've put it together how it makes sense in my head. (I'm aware this may not be correct or function as intended.) My question is in regard to the child code algorithm near the bottom.
- How do I implement this so each child does 1/nth of the work, and finds the longest match, even though it may not match 100%?
- Final output would be:
  `./DNA 6 sequence1 subsequence1
  Looking for string using 6 processes...
  Best match is at position 123456 with 9876/10240 correct.`

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: You can use Dynamic Programming concepts, you will need a memoization.

Comment: Look at Longest Increasing subsequence problem. Your problem seems similar. If you need to know the string as well, be sure to save the start and end index of the largest string

Comment: @JohnBollinger Question has been updated. Thanks.

Comment: Do they have to match lengths, or can you have insertions or deletions?

Comment: I suggest getting it working with very much shorter strings, in a single process. Then it is testable and verifiable. When happy with that, divide it between processes and only when that is good, give it the full data.

Comment: @stark I'm not sure what you're asking here. It will search for 'subsequence1' within 'sequence1'. This will always return some sort of match (worst case being 1, only the first character). I'm looking for clarification on how to implement this within my child code, so they each do 1/nth of the searching before the parent puts out the final result in the above form.

Comment: The problem statement seems straightforward and remarkably simple, while the proposed solution horribly complicated.  Am I missing something here?  Weird tags too - every non-trivial code will have a for loop - why that tag?  And while you have used a semaphore and fork, a solution does not require either - your question is not really about any of those things as far as I can determine.

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane. I've done it that way so far (small file, 1 as my process input) so it doesn't take forever to test. I've gone back and forth on a few algorithms trying to work out the kinks, but this is (unfortunately) my best work so far when using more than one process.

Comment: @Clifford I'm new to C and am working on getting better with shared memory, semaphores, and fork(). I wanted to implement it where multiple children split up the work. I'll axe a couple of the tags. Thanks.

Comment: @C.j. OK, I see.

Comment: You are missing a digit in the size of sequence.

Comment: @NiVeR Got that taken care of. The one in the code was correct, the question was not. It's been edited for clarity and needs as well. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you decide to use processes vs threads?  I get the attempt at parallelism but threads + mutex is simpler than forks + semiphores imo.

Comment: @Bwebb Good question. Like i said, for the most part, it's an exercise. I'm familiar with the use of threads and a mutex, but am pretty clueless when it comes to processes and semaphores. I would like to brush up on my knowledge in this space.

Comment: If you are trying to learn processes and semaphores then your title is misleading, and it's a repeat question, for which you should simply look for an easier example.  
If you are truly trying to solve the problem that you titled, then your approach is your question has its own complexity and your approach is not going to yield the correct results, and your parallelism is not going to work.